# 'service docker status' fails: invalid arguments

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm having trouble installing docker inside docker.

Outer docker works just fine but inner docker behavior is doubtful. I've followed all steps in [official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) but after installation when I call status it still shouts error:

```
$ > sudo service docker status
/etc/init.d/docker: invalid arguments
 * could not access PID file for Docker
```

BTW starting service works fine:

```
$ > sudo service docker start
* Starting Docker: docker                                                      [ OK ]
```

But `docker` itself seems to be working properly. `hello-world` is working and all other experiment I'm doing are also working so far. But I'm not sure I won't stumble upon some other issue later on.

I tried using several OS combinations. For outer OS i used `Centos 7` and `LinuxMint 17.3` and inner OS `ubuntu:14.04` and `ubuntu:16.04` but result is always the same (so I'm guessing it has to do something with `ubuntu`).
Outer docker is running docker with `--privileged` flag.

---

So it looks like this:

```
[outer OS Centos 7] docker run -ti --privileged ubuntu:14.04 bash
    [inner OS Ubuntu] sudo service docker status
```

Thanks for the help,

x3mSpeedy

Comment: docker container usually don't have an init system. Please post your Dockerfile. Did you really run both commands inside the container?

Comment: I build image using [this](https://gist.github.com/x3mSpeedy/da7c48e1b717ed75b5bf2501369c2a6f) Dockerfile

Comment: Here is [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o9fs45iy1unp85j/screen-shot.png?dl=0) of both commands.

Comment: Try not using sudo since the user is root (can tell by the `#` symbol)

Comment: Thank for the advise, but I'm getting same result with using `sudo` and without it